# Clickhouse data skipping index suggestion

Tags: clickhouse

We have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.maptest
(
    `k` Int64,
    `map` Map(String, String),
    INDEX idx_custom_attributes_keys mapKeys(map) TYPE bloom_filter GRANULARITY 3,
    INDEX idx_custom_attributes_values mapValues(map) TYPE bloom_filter GRANULARITY 3
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY k
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

insert into maptest 
select 
    number, 
    map(concat('custom', toString(number%87000)), toString(number%87000)) 
from numbers(200000000);
```

When we run the following query, data skipping indexes are used:

```
SELECT count()
FROM maptest
WHERE (map['custom2']) = '2';

[6edf3889c382] 2023.10.13 11:54:48.201726 [ 49 ] {4d4d2d04-e229-4f66-b90c-0c4efbb1ec6c} <Debug> default.maptest (4f9508c6-81b3-4d97-a589-95aa02499ce0) (SelectExecutor): Index `idx_custom_attributes_keys` has dropped 5840/8139 granules.
[6edf3889c382] 2023.10.13 11:54:48.201784 [ 49 ] {4d4d2d04-e229-4f66-b90c-0c4efbb1ec6c} <Debug> default.maptest (4f9508c6-81b3-4d97-a589-95aa02499ce0) (SelectExecutor): Index `idx_custom_attributes_values` has dropped 0/2299 granules.

...

1 row in set. Elapsed: 1.945 sec. Processed 56.50 million rows, 2.33 GB (29.05 million rows/s., 1.20 GB/s.)
```

However in the production application we use `accurateCastOrNull` function, because we store different types of data (Strings, Integers, Floats, Boolean), and when running any query like the one below, indexes are not used:

```
SELECT count()
FROM maptest
WHERE accurateCastOrNull(map['custom2'], 'String') = '2'

1 row in set. Elapsed: 2.033 sec. Processed 200.00 million rows, 8.35 GB (98.35 million rows/s., 4.11 GB/s.)
```

Is there any way to adapt the index definition for this function or another way to enforce this?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try setting `force_data_skipping_indices` to `idx_custom_attributes_keys`. If it doesn't use that skipping index, the query will fail.